# Trigger Java process detecting record meeting specific condition

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-integration

I am working on a Java Project using Spring. Database is Oracle
We have a Message listener configured in the container attached to a remote queue. Following are the steps we do once the onMessage gets triggered

1. Parse the message
2. insert the message in the database.
3. Based on the content of the message do some additional process involving file processing, DB insert/update etc..

If the message received in the queue is good and due to some issue on our side, we were unable to process it, We do not have a way to reprocess the message after waiting for some time [assuming the issue which triggered the error gets resolved].

Following is the new design proposed.
1. Parse the message
2. insert the message in the database with a flag. say "false" [The flag only gets changed when the message gets successfully processed.]

A New process to be added which queries the database for record flagged as "false" [one at a time], process it and update the flag to true. If the processing fails, retry configurable amount of time to process the same record. The process can die if there are no more records to process or have exhausted the retry count...

Please suggest a reasonable design which process the message at the earliest possible time detecting a record flagged as "false'

1. Trigger a java process using Database Trigger ? [DBA is against it]
2. Is there a way we can trigger the process in the onMessage method after the Database insert is done and without blocking the retrieval of next message ?
3. Scheduling a job which polls the database at regular interval ?

Comment: Does your processing code have to be in Java or can you use PL/SQL?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in Spring with the `@Async` annotation. This annotation allows to launch a task asynchronously after the completion of the insert.

This means the thread that made the insert will not block while the `@Async` operation runs, and it will return immediately.

Depending on the task executor configured, the `@Async` will get executed in a separate thread, which is what you need in this case. I would suggest to start with `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`, see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) what are the different task executors available.

Check also this [Spring tutorial](http://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/) for further info.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using Spring Integration, why not just send the enhanced message to a new channel and process it there? If the channel is a `QueueChannel` the processing will be ansynchronous. There are retry features available as well.

Comment: If the retry fails, the application is expected to go down. When the application comes up again, we need to process the message. [At that time the message is not available in the queue since we are not pushing it back to the queue on failure]

Comment: There is no need for an app to fail when a retry fails (but it's up to you). I guess you have persisted the message somewhere? So you might need to have a background process, or just a single action triggered on startup, to process messages that are still failed but unprocessed. It's a bit of an open-ended question at this point, so I think you should try something and then come back with more questions on specific topics.

Comment: Thanks Dave.... To be more precise.. I would need to implement a process which picks the message from the table [the data being persisted by the MQ listener] as soon as it gets inserted in the database. What is the best way to implement this to reflect as if the message just came out of the queue [ in a non error scenario]?